# UIActivityViewController is not working in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
NSString *sharedMsg = sharecontent;
NSArray *sharedObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sharedMsg, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharedObjects applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when i am sharing

getting this not able to share

```
plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated
plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated
plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post
```

Comment: i  am in device only

Comment: It is not a bug, is due to a new policy restriction. But we share content .

Comment: how i can do , where i need to change

Comment: Can you share the content

Comment: Download the app here wwww.test.com or Redeem it at www.test.com